# DBSCAN and border points

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, dbscan

It is being said that DBSCAN is not consistent on the border points and depends on which cluster it assigns the point to first.
Is there a variation of DBSCAN which takes into account the number of points a border point is close to (eps) in each cluster, when it wants to assign a border point to one of the clusters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those cases where this matters, the number of points will usually be 1 for two clusters each.

The better tie breaker will be the distance, but even that can have ties.

It is a trivial modification, easily implemented in post-processing: for every border point, find the nearest core point, and use that label.

However, does it matter?

Clustering is never perfect. And we are talking here about a rare case where the "best" (for a rather ad-hoc definition of "best", based on two  hard thresholds) assignment **usually makes 0.000 difference** to the end result.

If I am not mistaken, the DBSCAN author suggested that you can also **assign these points to both clusters**. That is supposedly the solution most true to the definitions (the border point *is* reachable from both clusters). But it makes everything much more complicated. Because many users want each point to have *one* label in a nice numeric column, and not have to deal with this special case.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but still: first of all, a border point must be a core point itself because there must be at least one further object in its epsilon neighborhood from which it is directly density reachable. Otherwise it would not be connected to a cluster.

By definition the DBSCAN result is deterministic w.r.t. the core and noise points but not w.r.t the border points, so: if a border point is density reachable from two clusters it really depends on the processing or your implementation, to which cluster it will be assigned.

Comment: >  "first of all, a border point must be a core point itself."


This is incorrect per the definition of the [paper](https://www.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/Publikationen/Papers/KDD-96.final.frame.pdf). By definition 2 of *directly density-reachable* the relationship between a border point p and a corer point q is not symmetric.